# Parsedown for PHP blockquotes

Tags: php, markdown, parsedown

I'm using [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/tests/simple_blockquote) for a project. Having trouble with the quotes:

```
$text = ">here's a quote <br><br> reply to quote";
echo $Parsedown->text($text);
```

is outputting

```
<blockquote>
    <p>
        "here's a quote "
        <br>
        <br>
        " reply to quote"
    </p>
</blockquote>
```

whereas I want the blockquote to end after the second `<br>`, then have the reply as a simple `p`. How should the text be, does it use newlines not breaks or something?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, can you try using new lines instead (`$text = "> here's a quote" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "reply to quote"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your string should be:

```
">here's a quote <br><br>

reply to quote"
```

Check here: [**http://parsedown.org/demo**](http://parsedown.org/demo)

Comment: How can those new lines be stored in a database text field?